# Strange TCP connections (every 25 seconds) on my azure cloud service

Tags: azure, tcp

A few days ago, something strange started to appear on my azure cloud service.
Every 25 seconds, a TCP connection from 13.95.160.11 is made.

It's an Microsoft Azure IP.
It has never done this before.

At first, I was thinking about a load balancer configuration but there is nothing about it in the documentation.

Here is my csdef Endpoints :

```
<Endpoints>
    <InputEndpoint name="HttpEndpoint" protocol="http" port="8080" />
    <InputEndpoint name="TcpEndpoint" protocol="tcp" port="12345"/>
    <InternalEndpoint name="TcpInternal" protocol="tcp" />
</Endpoints>
```

I have also tried to downgrade my azure SDK from 2.9 to 2.8, but nothing change.

I don't know what I am missing, do you have any idea on what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same problem and I asked on MSDN forums. This was the answer provided by a moderator:

> IP address is related to Microsoft Azure in order to monitor the health (Keep connection alive).

[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/65750bd7-4060-4c8c-83c0-ac32c26a8376/something-is-connecting-and-disconnecting-to-my-worker-role?forum=windowsazuredevelopment).